Errores de compilacion en codigo html y razor
Tengo un proyecto en VS2022 creado en .Net 6.0 MVC para web (NetCore), actualize VS y comenzo a mandar errores de compilacion en codigo que no presentaba ningun problema, por ejemplo este fragmento de codigo
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label asp-for="CandidateQuestFileName" class="control-label"></label>
    @{
        @if (Model.CandidateQuestFileId != null)
        {
            <div class="input-like-link col-md-12">
                <a href="/Pdf/ViewFileLibraryPdf?id=@Model.CandidateQuestFileId" target="_blank" title="View document"><i class="fa-solid fa-file-pdf pe-2"></i>@Model.CandidateQuestFileName</a>
            </div>
        }
        else
        { 
            <input class="form-control input-disabled-bgcolor" placeholder="File not uploaded" disabled />
        }   //Esta línea es la que genera un error
    }
</div>

Este es el error que manda el compilador:
Error (activo)   CS1525  El término de expresión '<' no es válido    RTS_RecruiterSystem C:\Development\VS_Projects\Repository_GitHub\RTS_RecruiterSystem\RTS_RecruiterSystem\Views\Vacancy  C:\Development\VS_Projects\Repository_GitHub\RTS_RecruiterSystem\RTS_RecruiterSystem\Views\Vacancy\Details.cshtml   257
Me llama la atención que marque un error en la llave de apertura de la etiqueta '<'.
Y así me arrojo una lista muy grande de errores.
¿Alguna idea o sugerencia por que están generado estos errores?
¿Seria recomendable, actualizar el proyecto a .Net 7?
Gracias de antemano por sus respuestas.

Limpiaste la solucion? reiniciaste??? suena a esas cosas cuando algo compila mal y entonces empieza a tirar cualquier cosa...

Si, limpie la solución, recompile consulte varios foros, IA's y en general sugerían indentar bien el codigo, revisar los cierres, pero nada funciono.

Luego de buscar en muchísimos sitios y consultar con el Autopilot de MS, no encontré ninguna solución a los errores, pero pude corregir el problema.
La solución fue:
Revertir la actualización de Visual Studio y se corrigieron los errores que se presentaron.
Aunque esta "solución" es solo momentánea, ya que en algún momento tendré que actualizar el VS y sus componentes, seguramente se van a presentar los mismos errores.
Debido a que es un sistema de mas de 100 mil líneas de código, por el momento no  quiero actualizar a .Net 7 o superior.
Pero tendré que prepararme para los posibles problemas al migrar a una versión mas nueva.
Gracias por su ayuda

La terrible situación de tener que mantener sistemas desarrollados con herramientas que ya desaparecieron del mercado. Lamentable. Suerte
